# Nunit setup virtual property on repository mock

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nunit, moq

I am trying to test a method that uses the following domain objects.

```
public class PartyRoom
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Capacity { get; set; }
    public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RoomBooking> Bookings { get; set; }
}

public class RoomBooking
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public BookingType BookingType { get; set; }
    public int PartyRoomId { get; set; }
    public int TimeSlotId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public virtual PartyRoom PartyRoom { get; set; }
    public virtual TimeSlot TimeSlot { get; set; }
}

public enum BookingType
{
    PartyOrder,
    RoomRental,
    Corporate
}
```

I have a repository mock I am setting up for the room bookings like this:

```
_roomBookingRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.Get()).Returns(roomBookings.AsQueryable);
```

The `roomBookings` being returned looks like this:

```
var roomBookings = new List<RoomBooking>
{
    new RoomBooking()
    {
        Id = 1,
        BookingType = BookingType.PartyOrder,
        Date = new DateTime(2014, 11, 15),
        PartyRoomId = 2,
        TimeSlotId = 1
    },
    new RoomBooking()
    {
        Id = 2,
        BookingType = BookingType.PartyOrder,
        Date = new DateTime(2014, 11, 15),
        PartyRoomId = 4,
        TimeSlotId = 3
    },
    new RoomBooking()
    {
        Id = 3,
        BookingType = BookingType.PartyOrder,
        Date = new DateTime(2014, 11, 15),
        PartyRoomId = 5,
        TimeSlotId = 4
    }
};
```

What is happening when I run the test is that `public virtual ICollection<RoomBooking> Bookings { get; set; }`is always null. I am not sure how to setup up that property as my roombookings list is not mocked so `SetupGet` doesn't appear to work?

When I run the test I get:

> System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.

Which when stepping through shows me the property is null. I guess I can't assume NUnit will wire this up like Entity Framework does in code first but I am stumped as to how I can access this and setup the property.

*I posted as much of the code as I can, the method itself I can't share for project reasons but I can confirm the issue is that the property is null and not getting setup.

Comment: 'What is happening when I run the test...' Could you post your test as well?

Comment: It seems the `Bookings` property you talk about is part of the `PartyRoom` class, but you never use it in your code. Also, when you create an instance of `PartyRoom`, sure `Bookings` is `null` if you never change it. What did you expcet to happen? Sorry, it's not clear to me.

Comment: Bookings is linked as a virtual property to the roomBookingsRepository and when running normally pulls in the bookings that are linked to the party room id. It's a one to many relationship in EF. I think I'll likely need to mock out my DBSet to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using Entity Framework it creates an object graph in memory of the information retrieved from the database.  Part of this is that it will use virtual properties to fetch information from other tables for you.

When you're writing unit tests, you don't want to hit the database, so you typically mock out your data access which is what you're doing here, by creating a mock of your repository.  The problem you have is that, because you're not hitting the Entity Framework classes, it isn't going to populate your domain objects for you.  You're already doing part of the job, by creating your list of `RoomBooking`, but you need to create *all* of the objects that your system under test relies on.

At a basic level, you just need to change the way you create your `roomBookings` to include the missing information.  Something like this should do the trick:

```
var roomBookings = new List<RoomBooking>();
roomBookings.Add(new RoomBooking()
{
    Id = 1,
    BookingType = BookingType.PartyOrder,
    Date = new DateTime(2014, 11, 15),
    PartyRoomId = 2,
    TimeSlotId = 1,
    PartyRoom = new PartyRoom {
        Bookings = roomBookings
    }
});
roomBookings.Add(new RoomBooking()
{
    Id = 2,
    BookingType = BookingType.PartyOrder,
    Date = new DateTime(2014, 11, 15),
    PartyRoomId = 4,
    TimeSlotId = 3,
    PartyRoom = new PartyRoom {
        Bookings = roomBookings
    }
});
roomBookings.Add(new RoomBooking()
{
    Id = 3,
    BookingType = BookingType.PartyOrder,
    Date = new DateTime(2014, 11, 15),
    PartyRoomId = 5,
    TimeSlotId = 4,
    PartyRoom = new PartyRoom {
        Bookings = roomBookings
    }
});
```

Notice that I'm creating a `PartyRoom` entry for each `RoomBooking` and pointing  back to the list that I am creating.  This might not be the right thing to do (you might need to create a new `RoomBooking` list for each `PartyRoom` that only contains bookings for that room but without seeing your DB, I'm guessing).

Essentially, you need to create all of the objects that your tests and system under test relies on.

There are also frameworks such as [Autofixture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autofixture) that can help you to create your test objects, which it may be worth you considering.